# Python Pandas: how to get data from a website into a dataframe by searching for values following key words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, file-io

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566914/how-to-write-specific-values-from-a-pandas-python-dataframe-to-a-specific-plac/77567039#77567039) question recently and received very helpful advice.  I have been building on the advice but have again encountered a problem I can't solve.  I would be very grateful for any advice.

In my previous situation, I read data from a well-organized external file into a dataframe.  The data were already in columns and all I had to do to get the data was:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("organizedValues.txt", delimiter="\t")
```

In the current problem, the data I need are not in a well-organized file.  They're posted at a website.  **I want to put the data into a Pandas dataframe.**. Here are details.

There are many different molecules.  There's a separate webpage for each molecule and it always has the same structure.  Here's an example of how one molecule's webpage appears.

```
CH4   Methane                  
    13.00000        Things in unit                             
     4.00000        L, units in unit defintion                     
   262.22300        mMass (lb/mol)                              
   300.00000        K_0 (C)                                           
   100.45200        V_0 (m^3/mol)                                    
   719.08310        Eta_0 (-)                                       
     0.00000        Some parameter                           
     0.00000        Another parameter                           
     0.00000        Strain (-)                            
   200.00000        K_1 (C)
```

I followed advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252977/read-and-process-data-from-url-in-python) to read data from a URL and save it in a file.  Now I have a file called "ch4.txt."  The problem is that it's a mess.  I can't use "read_table" as I did in my previous post.  Here's a very small snippet as an example:

> {"name”:”test2”,”path”:”test2”,”contentType":"file"},{"name”:”test5”,”path”:”test”5,”contentType":"file"}],"totalCount”:500}},”fileTreeProcessingTime”:25,”foldersToFetch":[],"reducedMotionEnabled":null,"repo":{"id”:yyy,”defaultBranch":"main","name”:”code”name,”ownerLogin”:”username”,”currentUserCanPush":false,"isFork":false,"isEmpty":false,"createdAt":"2022-04-31T01:30:52.000Z",v=4","public":true,"private":false,"isOrgOwned":false},"symbolsExpanded":false,"treeExpanded":true,"refInfo":{"name":"main","listCacheKey”:”XXX”,”canEdit":false,"refType":"branch","currentOid”:”XXX”},”path”:”or”,”currentUser":null,"blob":{"rawLines":["
> CH4   Methane                  ","            13.00000        Strain
> (-)                             ","             0.00000   K_0 (C)
> ","         300.00000     Things in unit   ","             13.00000
> Eta_0 (-)   "," 756

I need to search the file for keywords like "`Strain (-)`" and then extract the values after the keywords (in this case, `0.00000`).  For this particular example, I would want to end up with a Pandas dataframe like:

```
    Name   Strain (-)   K_0 (C)    Things in unit  Eta_0 (-)
1   CH4    0.00000      300.00000  13.00000        756
```

A cleaner way to do it (so I won't be storing many files) would be to get the data directly from the website and read it into a dataframe in an organized way.  However, I have spent a few hours on trying to find information about how to do this and have not been successful.  If anyone has encountered this kind of thing before, I would love to know what worked.  Thank you.

Comment: That sample looks a lot like json. Post a minimum sample containing the expected text please. Questions are encouraged to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @LMC, thank you.  I edited the question to show the dataframe I'd want from the example.

Comment: you must post a valid json sample out of your ch4.txt file so your problem becomes reproducible. There's no way to help without a valid example. Also, the posted sample contains "curly" double quotes not allowed as quotes by many languages. Open the sample with a proper editor or use a mono font.

Comment: @LMC, I'm sorry, I don't understand.  This is not a json problem.  I'm using Python and the data are from a website.  When I save the data to a file, I get a file that contains the data I need (values after keywords).  I need to find out how to extract only the values and keywords into a dataframe.  Thank you..txt

Comment: You have to post a valid input sample instead of `a very small snippet as an example`. THe whole file may look like a mess to you but probably has an structured format that can be read with the proper tool. You can try renaming it to ch4.json and opening it with Notepad++ or any other code capable editor. Formating the file would help to identify how to extract information-

Comment: @LMC.  Thank you, but the file is hundreds of lines long.  I would like to find a Python method to look for particular strings and then extract values associated with them.  In the example I have provided, I would like to search for (for example) K_0 (C)
"," and then extract "300.00000."

Comment: Post at least a sample of `{"rawLines":[" CH4 Methane` until the next `]}`. Or post the URL where you get the info from

Comment: It looks like your data is in JSON format, so I would suggest trying `data = json.load(file); df = pd.json_normalize(data)` and see what you get, it might be obvious how to go from there to your desired result. [`json_normalize` manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a substring starting with `"blob"` can be extracted from the input (the sample is an incomplete fragment), here's how to convert that to a dataframe as expected

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# fragment may need to be surrounded with {}
rawstr = '''
{
  "blob": {
    "rawLines": ["CH4   Methane                  ",
    "            13.00000        Strain (-)                             ",
    "             0.00000   K_0 (C)     ",
    "         300.00000     Things in unit   ",
    "             13.00000  Eta_0 (-)   ", "756    ."
    ]
  }
}
'''

# parsing the fragment as json
data = json.load(StringIO(rawstr))

cdata = []
for v in data["blob"]["rawLines"]:
    vals = [x for x in v.strip().split(' ') if x != '']
    cdata.append([vals[0], " ".join(vals[1:])])

datadict = {}
datadict['Name'] = [cdata[0][0]]

for s in range(1,len(cdata) - 1):
    # value must be taken from next item in the list that's why it's s+1
    datadict[cdata[s][1]] = cdata[s+1][0]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=datadict, dtype=object)

print(df)
```

Result

```
  Name Strain (-)    K_0 (C) Things in unit Eta_0 (-)
0  CH4    0.00000  300.00000       13.00000       756
```

Comment: thank you!  Now I understand what you meant.  I didn't know there was a facility in Python for dealing with json-formatted files (or even what a json-formatted file would look like).  People at work will be excited to find out about this.